# angular 2 custom directive OnInit

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-directives

i'm just getting starting on Angular 2 and i'm encountering the following problem.

Below is a simple custom directive which is supposed to color the font green. However in the ngOnInit, it can't access the string "defaultColor", the console.log returns "undefined".

Any clue why?

Cheers!

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[myHighlight]'
})

export class HighlightDirective implements OnInit{
    private elRef:ElementRef;
    private defaultColor: 'green';

    constructor(elRef:ElementRef){
        this.elRef = elRef;
    }

    ngOnInit():any {
        this.elRef.nativeElement.style.color = this.defaultColor;
        console.log(this.defaultColor)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is wrong.

```
private defaultColor:string = 'green';
```

The value is assigned using `=` not `:`. `:` is to define a type for the field.

Comment: Hi Gunter:\! I understand there is a sysntax error. Still my code works. I don't know how. I have implemented the same as user has suggested.

Comment: I see. Might depend on the development tools you are using, how strict they are about syntax.

Comment: I have implemented it with `Plunker`.Still don't know why. Nevermind !

Comment: i was using webstorm and indeed private defaultColor: 'green'; was written in the tutorial...

Answer (score 1):

***[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/NvGBg5ZoyU4yCVeDmLT2?p=preview)***

***boot.ts***

```
import {Component,bind} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/form';
import {selectedColorDirective} from 'src/directive';
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, Input,ViewChild,AfterViewInit} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
          <div mySelectedColor> (div) I'm {{color}} color </div>
    `,
    directives: [selectedColorDirective]
})

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{

 }

bootstrap(AppComponent, []);
```

***directive.ts***

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({
    selector:"[mySelectedColor]", 
})

  export class selectedColorDirective { 

    private defaultColor: 'green';
     constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
      this.el=el;
        //this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = this.defaultColor; 
        this.el.nativeElement.style.color = this.defaultColor; 
     } 

        ngOnInit():any {
           this.elRef.nativeElement.style.color = this.defaultColor;
            console.log(this.defaultColor)
        }
    }
```